# PHP preg_replace unwanted characters and echo a message if such characters are found in the string

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match

The following PHP code doesn't work, how do i detect chars that are not alphabets or numbers and then echo some message?

```
$l = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/", "", $ll);
     if ( $l == ''){
    echo 'Please Enter your desired username.';
} else if($l != $ll){
    echo "Please enter only valid charecters";

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From php.net

> If matches are found, the new subject will be returned, otherwise subject will be returned unchanged or NULL if an error occurred.

So try

```
$l = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/", "", $ll);
if ( $l == null ){
    echo 'Please Enter your desired username.';
} else if($l != $ll){
    echo "Please enter only valid characters";
}
```

As a side note, please don't call your vars `$l` or `$ll`, other people (including yourself a few months down the line) have no idea what that means.

Comment: Undefined variable: ll in

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!preg_match('~^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$|.~s', $ll, $m))
    echo 'Please enter your desired username.';
elseif (empty($m[1]))
    echo 'Please enter only valid characters.';
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your if statement and modify your code to:

```
 if (preg_match("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/", $username))
      echo "Please enter only valid charecters";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `prag_match` to detect valid characters or not:

```
function checkValid($string) {
   return  preg_match('/[^A-Za-z0-9.#\\-$]/', $string) ? true : false;
}
```

It will return `true` if `valid` and `false` if `not valid`

Comment: Why are you adding those special char?

Comment: I thought they need to be identified too